# What is the default encryption type of the ssh-keygen?

Tags: ssh, security, encryption

When generating private/public keys with `ssh-keygen` what types of keys will it generate if I wont pass `-t` option followed with the encryption type like `rsa`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the man page:

> ssh-keygen can create RSA keys for use by SSH protocol version 1 and DSA, ECDSA or RSA keys for use by SSH protocol version 2. The type of key to be generated is specified with the -t option.  **If invoked without any arguments, ssh-keygen will generate an RSA key for use in SSH protocol 2 connections**.

So that's RSA by default. Note that `ssh-keygen` prints out what type of key it is generating in its first line of output.

Comment: Thanks... I was looking in the mand page but on a wrong place - in the `-t` option docs.