# What are the strengths and weaknesses of the ssh-keygen algorithms and is one of them the most secure?

Tags: ssh, security

I was wondering about the different types of keys you can create with `ssh-keygen -t` (dsa | ecdsa | ed25519 | rsa | rsa1). Since different types are offered I assume that each has a specific advantage over the others. Is that true? What are they? And since RSA is the default type ([Question 39321](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39321/what-is-the-default-encryption-type-of-the-ssh-keygen)), is that one the most secure? Can there be one which is *most* secure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't one algorithm that's the “most secure”. Once an algorithm has reached the point where it would take either a huge mathematical breakthrough or billions of billions of years of computing power, strength comparisons become meaningless.

The reason why RSA is common is that it's common. It's been around for a long time, so every implementation around supports RSA, so every implementation keeps offering RSA for interoperability.

[RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) is secure as long as you choose a large enough key size: 1024 is unbroken but might be broken in a few years by NSA-level attackers; 2048 (the default size for `ssh-keygen` in current versions of OpenSSH) is safe in the medium term. (RSA1 is an old version of the SSH protocol which has weaknesses and shouldn't be used anymore. It's just about extinct anyway.)

[DSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm) is limited to 1024-bit keys. You generally can't compare key sizes across algorithms, but between DSA and RSA, the strength is about the same. OpenSSH only supports 1024-bit keys because that was the maximum size in the old DSA standard (FIPS 186-2) and the SSH protocol wasn't updated. Since DSA-1024 is considered weak, it's somewhat deprecated, and [OpenSSH 7.0](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.0) disables it by default in the server configuration (the use of DSA keys in the SSH protocol is called `ssh-dss`).

[ECDSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm) is a newer family of algorithms; it's significantly faster than RSA or DSA for the same security level, and has smaller keys. ECDSA support is less ubiquitous than RSA, partly because it's newer and partly because of patents on efficient implementation techniques. Any key size supported by OpenSSH is secure.

[Ed25519](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdDSA#Ed25519) is a newer alternative to ECDSA. For an end user, it has no significant advantage over ECDSA (for an implementer, it carries less risk of patent infringement). But as it's newer, you may want to connect to machines that don't support it yet; that's less likely with ECDSA.

So the default RSA is fine, but if you use less powerful computers (e.g. low-end smartphone, router, …), prefer ECDSA (or Ed25519) if supported.

Answer (score 4):

There is similar answer on [Information Security Stackexchange site](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23383/ssh-key-type-rsa-dsa-ecdsa-are-there-easy-answers-for-which-to-choose-when). In practice, all of them should do their job.

- RSA is universal and should work everywhere
- DSA was disabled in recent openssh (7.1) and can perform worse with week random number  generator
- ECDSA is computationally lighter, but you will not notice the difference on today computers. Disadvantage is also fixed length of key (same for DSA).
- ED25519 is less widespread but shouldn't contain any backdoor by any national agency [source question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/50878/ecdsa-vs-ecdh-vs-ed25519-vs-curve25519)
- RSA1 is RSA key for old SSHv1 protocol which is obsolete and shouldn't be accepted by any modern server.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the other answers, as of 2019, ED25519 is becoming widely used and supported; most experts I follow believe it is a better choice than ECDSA (because it is thought to be free of any backdoor by any national security agency).

In summary, ECDSA is not fully trusted, RSA 1 is outdated. DSA is outdated. RSA (v2) is on the way out. That leaves only ED25519, if you are looking forward.

If something prevents me from using ED25519 I fall back to RSA v2 with a larger key size (4096 bits for me).

This is a very good discussion:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/50878/ecdsa-vs-ecdh-vs-ed25519-vs-curve25519

In particular, I like this answer:

https://security.stackexchange.com/a/53387/37051

From the [Introduction to Ed25519](http://ed25519.cr.yp.to/), there are some speed benefits, and some security benefits.  One of the more interesting security benefits is that it is immune to several side channel attacks:

> - No secret array indices. The software never reads or writes data from secret addresses in RAM; the pattern of addresses is completely predictable. The software is therefore immune to cache-timing attacks, hyperthreading attacks, and other side-channel attacks that rely on leakage of addresses through the CPU cache.
> - No secret branch conditions. The software never performs conditional branches based on secret data; the pattern of jumps is completely predictable. The software is therefore immune to side-channel attacks that rely on leakage of information through the branch-prediction unit.

from the answer by [brian-minton](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/32947/brian-minton)